# Is it possible to create an expression within the fieldCondition?

Tags: database

I'd like to patch a contributed module that has a nasty bug. Is it true that we can't use `fieldCondition()` for expressions (e.g. `a + b < 10`)?

This is the code I am using.

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->fieldCondition($field_name, 'runtime', 0, '!=')
    ->fieldCondition($field_name, 'runtime', $time, '+ node.created <') // BAD $operator!
    ->fieldCondition($field_name, 'active', 1, '=')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1);
  $result = $query->execute();
```

According to the current API, it's not possible to use '+ node.created <' as an $operator. Is there anything I could use other than a complete rewrite of this (custom SQL)?

Comment: why are you using this expression, what are you trying to achieve from this expression? Is it same as ($field_name['runtime']+node.created) < $time ??

Comment: Yes, it's the same as ($field_name['runtime']+node.created) < $time.